# Benchmarking methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark a set of computations like so -

```
def benchmark(func, index, array)
    start = Time.now
    func(index, array)
    start - Time.now #returns time taken to perform func
end

def func1(index, array)
    #perform computations based on index and array
end 

def func2(index, array)
    #more computations....
end

benchmark(func1, index1, array1)
benchmark(func1, index2, array2)
```

Now I'm wondering how can I achieve this. I tried this example, but is spits out

```
`func1': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

If I try -

```
benchmark(func1(index1, array1), index1, array1)
```

It spits out...

```
undefined method `func' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I saw a similar question asked about it, but it was for python. [Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python)
Can someone assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby, methods can be called without including empty parentheses after the method name, like so:

```
def func1
  puts "Hello!"
end

func1 # Calls func1 and prints "Hello!"
```

Because of this, when you write `benchmark(func1, index1, array1)`, you're actually calling `func1` with no arguments and passing the result to `benchmark`, not passing `func1` to the benchmark function as you expected. In order to pass `func1` as an object, you may obtain a wrapper object for the function using the [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Object.html#method-i-method) method, like this:

```
def func1
  puts "Hello!"
end

m = method(:func1) # Returns a Method object for func1
m.call(param1, param2)
```

Most of the time though, that's not something you really want to do. Ruby supports a construct called blocks which is much better suited for this purpose. You may already be familiar with blocks from the `each` iterator Ruby uses for looping through arrays. Here's what it would look like to use blocks for your use case:

```
def benchmark
  start = Time.now
  yield
  Time.now - start # Returns time taken to perform func
end

# Or alternately:
# def benchmark(&block)
#   start = Time.now
#   block.call
#   Time.now - start # Returns time taken to perform func
# end

def func1(index, array)
    # Perform computations based on index and array
end 

def func2(index, array)
    # More computations....
end

benchmark { func1(index1, array1) }
benchmark { func1(index1, array2) }
```

In fact, Ruby has a standard library for benchmarking called [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) which uses blocks and probably already does exactly what you want.

Usage:

> ```
> require 'benchmark'
>
> n = 5000000
> Benchmark.bm do |x|
>   x.report { for i in 1..n; a = "1"; end }
>   x.report { n.times do   ; a = "1"; end }
>   x.report { 1.upto(n) do ; a = "1"; end }
> end
> ```
>
> The result:
>
> ```
>     user     system      total        real
> 1.010000   0.000000   1.010000 (  1.014479)
> 1.000000   0.000000   1.000000 (  0.998261)
> 0.980000   0.000000   0.980000 (  0.981335)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.  I begin by creating a module contain all the methods to be tested:

```
module Methods
  def bob(array)
    ...
  end

  def gretta(array
    ...
  end

  def wilma(array)
    ...
  end
end
```

then I include the module and put the methods into an array:

```
include Methods
@methods = Methods.public_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:bob, :gretta, :wilma]
```

That allows me to execute `send(meth, *args)` for each method `meth` in `@methods`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617188/how-to-output-all-possible-combinations-using-loops-in-ruby)'s an example of this approach. You'll see I also have code to check that all methods return the same result and to format the output.

The main routine might look something like this:

```
test_sizes.each do |n|
  puts "\nn = #{n}"
  arr = test_array(n)
  Benchmark.bm(@indent) do |bm|
    @methods.each do |m|
      bm.report m.to_s do
        send(m, arr)
     end
    end
  end
end
```

I use a module so that methods to be benchmarked can be added, deleted or renamed without having to touch any code outside the module.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're attempting to use Ruby methods as functions. It's uncommon, but totally possible.

```
def benchmark(func, index, array)
    start = Time.now
    func.call(index, array) # <= (C)
    start - Time.now
end

def func1(index, array)
    #perform computations based on index and array
end 

def func2(index, array)
    #more computations....
end

benchmark(method(:func1), index1, array1) # <= (A)
benchmark(method(:func1), index2, array2) # <= (B)
```

The changes to your code are as follows:

**A, B)** Create a `Method` object out of your previously-defined methods. A `Method` object is like a `Proc` object in that it has a `call` method that allows you to invoke it later. In your code, when you just use `func1` rather than `method(:func1)`, what's happening is that you're immediately calling the method and passing its result to `benchmark`, rather than passing the function itself into `benchmark` for later invocation.

**C)** Use the `call` method. Ruby doesn't allow you to arbitrarily call variables as functions using parentheses the way some other languages do, but if it is an object type with a `call` method, like a `Method` or a `Proc`, you can use `call` to invoke the function when you're ready, instead of immediately before trying to pass it to another method, as in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SimpleBenchmarker
    def self.go(how_many=1, &block)
        $sorted_time = Array.new
        puts "\n--------------Benchmarking started----------------"
        start_time = Time.now
        puts "Start Time:\t#{start_time}\n\n"
        how_many.times do |a|
            print "."
            block.call
        end
        print "\n\n"
        end_time = Time.now
        puts "End Time:\t#{end_time}\n"
        puts "-------------Benchmarking finished----------------\n\n"
        result_time = end_time - start_time
        puts "Total time:\t\t#{result_time.round(3)} seconds\n\n"
        puts "The run times for the iterations from shortest to longest was: #{$sorted_time.sort.join("s, ")}s\n\n"
    end
end
    print "How many times? "
    t = gets.to_i
SimpleBenchmarker.go t do
    time = rand(0.1..1.0).round(3)
    $sorted_time.push(time)
    sleep time
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my new gem which can profile your ruby method (instance or class) - https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods.

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```